# Continuous on every continuous path vs Continuous

Tags: continuity

Suppose $F:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is such that for all continuous paths $g:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$, $F(g(t))$ is continuous.

Is F continuous?

Comment: What is your definition for $F$ to be continuous?

Comment: I guess the usual one ? Relatively to the usual topologies on $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$

Comment: The standard definition (For every series Xn->X0, f(Xn)->f(X0) or forall eps>0 exists delta>0 s.t. ...)

Comment: Every convergent sequence lies on a continuous path.

Comment: Why, and how do you prove it?

Answer (score 2):

Yes:  It suffices to show that $F(x_k)$ converges to $F(x)$ for any sequence $(x_k)$ in $\mathbb R^2$ that converges to $x$.  This convergence follows form the consideration of $g$ whose image is the polygonal path along this sequence ($g(1-1/k) = x_k$, $g(1) = x$).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Assume $F(0,0)=0$ and that $F$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$. Then there is an $\epsilon_0>0$ and a sequence $(z_n)_{n\geq1}$ with $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n=(0,0)$ and $|F(z_n)|\geq \epsilon_0$ for all $n\geq1$. After passing to a subsequence we may assume $|z_n|\leq 2^{-n}$ for all $n\geq1$. Put
$$g\left({1\over n}\right):=z_n\quad (n\geq 1), \quad g(0)=0,\quad g(-t)=g(t)$$
and extend $g$ to a piecewise linear function for $0<|t|\leq1$. Then $g:\ [-1,1]\to{\mathbb R}^2$ is a continuous path such that
$$t\mapsto F\bigl(g(t)\bigr)$$
is not continuous at $t=0$.